# how to static build qtcharts?

Tags: qt, nmake, qtcharts

I want to statically link to Qt components in my project. so I tried to build Qt from source. I followed these steps:

1. installed Qt source
2. opened VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt and changed directory to C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\Src\qtbase
3. in the file msvc-desktop.conf which is located in C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\common changed -MD and -MDd to -MT and -MTd
4. entered and ran this command: `configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc -mp -no-opengl -optimize-size`
5. entered and ran `nmake`

as the process of building Qt takes a lot of time and there is a lot of logs, I am not sure if everything went OK, but after this I could not find some of libraries like Qt5Charts.lib .

So my first question is this. with the steps i mentioned should Qt5Charts.lib be generated or not. if not what steps should i take to generate it?

my second question is, is there a way to build some parts of Qt from source without building the whole thing? I read somewhere that it is possible to do so using Qt creator, but how one can do it? how should one give the options like the option to build it statically?

Comment: Try `nmake module-qtcharts` now from `C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\Src` and see if there are any errors in the output.

Comment: it gives the error ```NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'module-qtcharts'```
Stop.

Comment: I think the problem is you need to configure in the Src folder not qtbase